# Where is the 'Require Participant Approval' checkbox on the 'Online Registration tab'?

Tags: civievent

I am trying to set up an event that requires participant approval.  I have read the guidance and have ensured that the participant statuses, 'Awaiting approval' and 'pending from approval' are enabled.

The guidance then goes on to say, 'You can then check the **Require Participant Approval** checkbox on the online registration tab', but I can't see this checkbox on the tab.

Am I missing something?
Thanks
Anna

Civi 4.6.5

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable 'Rejected' participant status as well.

"Require participant approval?" checkbox will appear only after you enable the following participant Statuses

- Awaiting Approval
- Pending from approval
- Rejected

Looks like the book/docs is not updated.